# Python Simple Encryption program: How to loop Z back to A

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I'm trying to make an encryption function that encrypts plaintext messages but the problem is that if i input a key too large that goes past 'Z' then it goes onto greater unicode values.

My code:

```
def encrypt(var1,var2): 
    var3 = ""
    for i in range(0, len(var1)):
        if ord(var1[i])>64 and ord(var1[i])<90:
            var3=var3+chr((ord(var1[i])+var2))
        elif ord(var1[i])+var2>90:
            ???
        else:
            continue
    return(var3)
```

How do I get it to loop 'Z' back to 'A'. I think I have to make an if statement like this but I'm not sure what to put into it.

```
elif ord(var1[i])+var2>90:
    ???
```

Comment: I think you need to provide some example input.

Comment: var2=30, var1=zzzz makes it ^^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my one! Im using the modulus operator to wrap around every 26 numbers (the number of letter between a-z). I also handle upper on lowercase separately.

```
def encrypt(data, shift):
    result = ''
    for c in data:
        c_num = ord(c)

        #  is the letter lower case a - z?
        if (c_num >= ord('a')) and (c_num <= ord('z')):
            #  get the letter number from 0 - 26
            c_num = c_num - ord('a')
            # shift the number
            c_num += shift
            # wrap the number every 26 numbers
            c_num = c_num % 26
            # now increase a by the new amount
            c_num += ord('a')
            result += chr(c_num)

        #  is the letter upper case A - Z?
        elif (c_num >= ord('A')) and (c_num <= ord('Z')):
            #  get the letter number from 0 - 26
            c_num = c_num - ord('A')
            # shift the number
            c_num += shift
            # wrap the number every 26 numbers
            c_num = c_num % 26
            # now increase a by the new amount
            c_num += ord('A')
            result += chr(c_num)

    return result

encrypt('aAbB', 2)
'cCdD'

encrypt('afZz', 2)
'chBb'
```

Here is the code golf version using list comprehension just for fun!

```
def encrypt(data, shift):
    return ''.join([chr(((ord(c) - ord('a') + shift) % 26) + ord('a')) if ord(c) in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1) else chr(((ord(c) - ord('A') + shift) % 26) + ord('A')) for c in data])
```

Answer (score 0):

A straight-forward way would be to check if you have passed beyond Z, and modify the character in that case:

```
...
if var1[i] >= 'A' and var1[i] <= 'Z':
    translated_char = chr(ord(var1[i])+var2)
    if translated_char > 'Z':
        # If the resulting character is beyond Z,
        # we go 26 characters back
        translated_char = chr(ord(translated_char)-26)
    # Append the translated character to the output string
    var3 += translated_char
...
```

You may want to consider more descriptive variable names -- you'll thank yourself if you revisit your code after two months :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the modulus operator to do what you are wanting.  In python that is the % character.  In modulus math.  X % Y tells us what the remainder of X / Y is.  For example.  27 % 26 is 1.  Using this you can get your wrap around that you want.  Here is a sample bit of code to encrypt a single character

```
def encrypt_character( valToEncrypt, keyVal ):

      # Update the character to be our standard Alphabet mapping
      # A -> 0; B->1 ... Z -> 25
      x = ord(valToEncrypt) - ord('A')

      # Perform the Encryption
      retVal = ( x + keyVal ) % 26

      # Translate back to the standard ASCII mapping of the character
      # for display in python and translate it back into a string
      retVal = chr(retVal + ord('A'))

      return retVal
   # end encrypt_character
```

Now if we feed the character "A" Into our encryption algorithm with a key of 13 we get "N" as shown:

```
>>> encrypt_character("A", 13)
'N'
```

The decrypt algorithm is very similar, except you do subtraction instead of addtion

```
def decrypt_character( valToDecrypt, keyVal ):

      # Update the character to be our standard Alphabet mapping
      # A -> 0; B->1 ... Z -> 25
      x = ord(valToDecrypt) - ord('A')

      retVal = ( x - keyVal ) % 26

      # Translate back to the standard ASCII mapping of the character
      # for display in python and translate it back into a string
      retVal = chr(retVal + ord('A'))

      return retVal
```

To encrypt a string you can use the following function:
    from re import sub
    def encrypt_message( message, key ):
         # Convert the message text into a plain text with all spaces and
         # punctuation removed.
         plainText = sub(r'[^A-Z]', '', message.upper())
         cipherText = ""

```
     charIndex = 0

     # Encrypt the message 1 character at a time
     while charIndex < len(plainText):
        cipherText += \
           encrypt_character( plainText[charIndex], key)
        charIndex += 1
     return cipherText
```

This function can be called:

```
>>> encrypt_message("HELLO World!", key=23)
'EBIILTLOIA'
```

The decryption function is very similar to the encryption function, except it calls the decrypt utility instead of the encrypt utility.

Comment: ok but how would I make it for an entire string instead of one characater?

Comment: Generally the process you need to follow is to strip out all punctuation, spaces, and convert everything to Upper (or lower) case.  I will update the example.